# Wordpress custom post type with folder structure in slug

Tags: posts, customization, slug

I have setup a custom post type with the slug "interview" and it is working fine. I am trying to change the slug to "magazine/interview" but I keep getting 404 errors when I try to access the posts that are already there. 
Is there any specific trick to set a slug with "/" characters in it?

Comment: how are you registering your post type? have you tried visiting the permalinks settings page in admin to flush the rewrite rules?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure to flush rewrite rules after changing the permalink structure, this can be done by visiting the `Settings > Permalinks` page in admin.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any way to use "/" in slug. I have Another solution for you. Create custom post type with slug "magazine" and create category "interview" now you have desired url "magazine/interview".

Comment: you absolutely can have a `/` in the slug

Comment: Milos is right. It worked fine after flushing the permalinks by re-saving the permalink settings.